# Updating a page's html with another and its impact on google search/ meta tags

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a website that has functionality like that of Material Design by Google here:

https://material.io/design/layout/applying-density.html#baseline-grid

I need to update the content of the page, URL and meta tags on clicking certain buttons as you can see on Material Design (left navigation bar visible on larger displays). So it is not just about changing content in one id in the HTML body. It might be more than one id as observed on inspecting changes made on Material Design.

I would like to refer to this question here:

[How to update page html and url without actual page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922286/how-to-update-page-html-and-url-without-actual-page-refresh)

From the above case, I learnt about pushState and have understood that bit. But it does not explain to me how I can build something like Material Design as it feels very seamless, yet retains the meta tags etc.

I am trying to understand the concept so I don't have any HTML to share. Please educate me on this matter and I will be grateful if you could provide me with a solution. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to manipulate a webpage without refreshing look into JS or some of its frameworks and libraries like React, jQuery, etc. But:
Maybe it's just me but the Material design website seems to load different pages whenever you click something, why don't you just do that?

Comment: Hi Chaz, I want a seamless experience on my website and don't want any loading screens, refreshes etc. Hence, I want to build something similar to Material Design. Can I achieve that by loading different complete webpages into the main page? Please let me know how I can do that. I saw tutorials on how to load some content into a specific id only, not complete pages...

Comment: There are dozens of ways to manipulate webpages without refreshing the whole page, you might want to look into topics like Javascript and its libraries and frameworks (jQuery, Angular, Vue, React) or AJAX

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically updating content of web page without refreshing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51479513/dynamically-updating-content-of-web-page-without-refreshing-it)

Comment: I will check it out in detail. Seems like a good starting point. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The material design website probably uses a framework, which is just a way of coding so that the framework will handle a lot of your stuff, one example of such framework is "ReactJS" made by facebook.

in react you could just do something like:

```
function MainContent() {
  return(
    <div id="main page">
      {{
        pageNumber == 0 ? <Page1 /> : 
        pageNumber == 1 ? <Page2 /> :
        // etc etc....
      }}
    </div>
  );
}
```

more examples of these "frameworks" are: vuejs, angular, svelte.
if you're not going to use any framework, you will simply have to deal with a lot of document.getElementById's and a lot of nasty DOM manipulation

Comment: Hi Luke! Thanks for the advice. I understand your argument but if I were to try building it without a framework (I am using just vanilla js), can you point me to a relevant resource? I tried very hard but did not come across anything useful. Maybe I am searching for something else incorrectly. I am open to jquery too if necessary. Sadly, I know nothing about these other frameworks....

Comment: I really do recommend to stay away from JQuery as it is a very old framework that nowadays has nothing to offer that vanilla js cant do, however more modern frameworks inlcuding react have things like "components" which allows you store a whole block of HTML code in a js variable, and then display it inside other html at certain conditions, if you want, here is a tutorial for ReactJS (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycrhfkZUKT0) its a crutial tool for modern websites, and it offers just what you need. also react is one of the simplest frameworks to learn

Comment: its basicly just javascript that is able to return HTML code, and that HTML code can contain javascript variables

Comment: I agree, that React is probably the best library to use for this.

Comment: I am not using jquery on my present website either. I will check out React. Thanks to both of you!